# Post input of choicefield into django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a basic form through which data can be entered into django model database. Everything works fine except the choicefield which does not post value to the database.I want the user to select from 'Morning' and 'Evening' (default value should be blank) which can then be posted to 'time' model.

Following is my models.py:

```
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    cow1 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    cow2 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    cow3 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    cow4 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Views.py:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
       cow1 = request.POST.get("cow1", False)
       cow2 = request.POST.get("cow2", False)
       cow3 = request.POST.get("cow3", False)
       cow4 = request.POST.get("cow4", False)
       time = request.POST.get("time", False)


       ins = models.cow(cow1=cow1, cow2=cow2, cow3=cow3, cow4=cow4, time=time)
       ins.save()
    return render(request, 'dataentry/home.html')
```

And home.html:

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="cow1">cow1</label>
    <input id="cow1" type="number" name="cow1">
    <label for="cow2">cow2</label>
    <input id="cow2" type="number" name="cow2">
    <label for="cow3">cow3</label>
    <input id="cow3" type="number" name="cow3">
    <label for="cow4">cow4</label>
    <input id="cow4" type="number" name="cow4">


    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <select form="time" name="time" id="time">
        <option value="time">Morning</option>
        <option value="time">Evening</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Little help will be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change the value option to Morning and Evening.

The name attribute in *select* is the key.

The value attribute in *option* is the value

Your code returns "time":"time"

with this :

```
<select name="time" id="time">
    <option value="none" selected disabled hidden> 
      Select an Option 
    </option> 
    <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
    <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
</select>
```

It will return "time":"Morning"
or "time":"Evening"

I delete the form attribute in select tag because there is no need to do that in your case.

But if you want to keep it, you can add id= "time" in your `<form action = "" method = "POST">`

You should consider to use ModelForm (a real timesaver)

Comment: did you delete form="time" in the select tag ?

Comment: No, it is still there

Comment: can you try without this attribute? form="time" specifiy the parent form of your select. No need to do that. And it leads to your False value in time field

Comment: Indeed. You can add id= "time" in your <form action = "" method = "POST"> OR delete form="time" in the select tag

Comment: Bingo, that worked.Lastly, the dropdown shows "morning" as a default. How do I change it to something blank or some text like "choose time"? Thanks

Comment: I edit my answer, and add the default text in dropdown with         <option value="none" selected disabled hidden> 
          Select an Option 
      </option>